# Building GCC without mpc, mpfr and gmp

Tags: gcc, toolchain, gnu-toolchain, linux-toolchain

I need to use lesser version of packages for building my toolchain. Is there anyway to build gcc by disabling the mpc, mpfr and gmp packages?

Answer (score 4):

There is a script called `contrib/download_prerequisites` in the GCC source tree.  From the [installation instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html):

> Likewise the GMP, MPFR and MPC libraries can be automatically built together with GCC. You may simply run the `contrib/download_prerequisites` script in the GCC source directory to set up everything. Otherwise unpack the GMP, MPFR and/or MPC source distributions in the directory containing the GCC sources and rename their directories to `gmp`, `mpfr` and `mpc`, respectively (or use symbolic links with the same name).

In order to be effective, the script If `contrib/download_prerequisites` must be invoked in the top-level directory of the source tree (i.e, the directory which contains `contrib` as a subdirectory).

As a result, GMP, MPFR and MPC will be bundled, and do not have to be installed separately for use by the rest of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to avoid using the packages GMP, MPFR and MPC to build Gcc. Is there a way to build Gcc without those packages

Comment: No. But you do not actually have to install these packages, so it's just as if they weren't there.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your point, does you mean these packages are not necessary for building GCC, if so while configuring I am gett error which expects for headers from those packages...

Comment: I hope, You work with glibc, Have you got a chance to look into sprof profiling, which leads to Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 707: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!

Comment: Regarding the profiling issue, please file a bug report against the relevant distribution. Thanks.

Comment: If you run `contrib/download_prerequisites` in the toplevel directory of the source tree, the `configure` script will subsequently pick up the downloaded sources and use them. The system packages are no longer required.